# Control which users can authenticate with Windows SMTP Server

Tags: windows, smtp

Is it possible to control which users in a domain can connect to the Microsoft IIS SMTP server? How is this managed?

Specifically, is it possible to restrict this to a single user?

The server is in a domain, but will only be used for a single application to send mail out to a smart host, so it doesn't need to be fully functional as a mail server.

The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 (with the IIS6 SMTP server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told us what version of Windows, but here's the instructions for IIS6 on Win2k3

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/58f05ef9-55a3-42b3-9f57-27fdc8723b8a.mspx?mfr=true

> In IIS Manager, right-click the SMTP virtual server, and then click
> Properties.
>
> Click the Access tab, and under Access control, click
> Authentication.

Set the appropriate options here. Basic auth or Windows Integrated, depending on your needs.

/Edit : I see. Yeah, I don't think it's full-featured enough to do granular security like that. Would restricting by IP work for you?

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/db81ac6a-4014-4189-91a2-12632d21aa64.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see anything in that guide about controlling which Windows users can use the SMTP server.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: That's kinda what I suspected. It would have made things slightly easier but not the end of the world if it doesn't work.